# MEAN return from http get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean

I'm learning to set up a MEAN app, but am stuck with retuning data into my app from a webservice. Just returning a simple variable is no problem, but how do I return the result from the webservice?

The result from the webservices is shown in de terminal console, but not on the frontend (angular). When I return e.g the options var it is shown in the frontend console, but the result from the webservice is not. Than I get `$promise: Object, $resolved: false,`

I'm building it with [MEAN.js](http://meanjs.org/)

This is what I have till now

shop.server.route.js

```
 'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var shop = require('../../app/controllers/shop.server.controller.js');


module.exports = function(app) {

    app.route('/shop')
        .get(shop.listProducts);

};
```

shop.server.controller.js

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http'),
    errorHandler = require('./errors.server.controller');

/**
 * List of Products
 */
exports.listProducts = function(req, res) {

    var options = {
        host: 'http://api.example.com',
        path: '/products?param1=1&param2=2'
    };



    req = http.get(options, function(res) {
        var body = {};

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            console.log('Got Response' + body );
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log( err.message);
        res.send('error:' + err.message);
    });



};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular works with async proccessing and callback digestions, which mean your http call retrun a promise object who get resolved when data arrived.

You should use angular's $http service. As mentioned in the documentation:

> The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and returns a promise with two $http specific methods: success and error.

You code should look like below (In the angular side):

```
var params = {};
params.param1 = 'paramdata';

$http.get('/shop', params).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
 // data will contain the results data
}).

error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // data will contain any error data
});
```

Feel free the extend your knowledge using the documentation - [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)